# JsonProvider "This is not a constant expression or valid custom attribute value"

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, type-providers, f#-data

Given the code:

```
#if INTERACTIVE
#r "bin\Debug\FSharp.Data.dll"

#endif

open System
open FSharp.Data
open FSharp.Data.Json

let testJson = """{ "workingDir":"hello", "exportDir":"hi there", "items":[{ "source":"", "dest":"", "args": {"name":"that"} }] }"""

//here is where i get the error
let Schema = JsonProvider<testJson>
```

The last line keeps giving me the error "This is not a constant expression or valid custom attribute value"-- what does that mean? How can i get it to read this JSON?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The string has to be marked as a constant. To do that, use [the  `[<Literal>]` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353581.aspx). Also, the type provider creates a type, not a value, so you need to use `type` instead of `let`:

```
open FSharp.Data

[<Literal>]
let testJson = """{ "workingDir":"hello", "exportDir":"hi there", "items":[{ "source":"", "dest":"", "args": {"name":"that"} }] }"""

type Schema = JsonProvider<testJson>
```

Comment: Thanks for this info. I am curious if anyone can explain in detail why you have to mark a value that is already immutable as a constant. What is really going on here? EDIT: nevermind, I get it. Obviously this has to all resolve at 'compile' time, not runtime.

Comment: @jackmott but why is this not the default?

Comment: @knocte short answer is that while an immutable value cannot change, it is not necessarily decided before the program is running. An immutable string could be set when a user inputs some data for instance.  In theory a compiler might in some cases be able to infer that a particular immutable string is a literal and make it so, but languages rarely try to do that, probably because it has non trivial complexity and compile time costs.

Answer (score 0):

The `JsonProvider` can be viewed as a parametrized JSON parser (plus the data type that the parser produces) that is specialized at compile time.

The parameter you give to it (a string or a path to JSON file) defines the structure of JSON data -- a schema if you wish. This allows the provider to create a type that will have all the properties your JSON data should have, statically, and the set of those properties (along with their respective types) are defined (actually inferred from) with the JSON sample that you give to the provider.

So the correct way to use the `JsonProvider` is shown in one of the examples from the documentation:

```
// generate the type with a static Parse method with help of the type provider
type Simple = JsonProvider<""" { "name":"John", "age":94 } """>
// call the Parse method to parse a string and create an instance of your data
let simple = Simple.Parse(""" { "name":"Tomas", "age":4 } """)
simple.Age
simple.Name
```

The example was taken from [here](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonProvider.html).

Comment: Yeah, except that you *can* use a variable, it just has to be marked as constant.

Comment: @svick, yes, there's the `Literal` attribute that allows to create the so-called named literals. But as you say, it makes the 'variable' a 'constant', which is a little contradictory, don't you agree? :)

Comment: Yeah, but I don't know about a good term that would describe both variables and constants.

Comment: @McMuttons That's not the same. For example `4` is a value, but `age` is a variable (or it could be a constant). `age` does contain a value, but it not a value itself.

Comment: @svick I suppose it depends on how you name things. To me anything that returns a fixed result is a value, whether it is a literal value, a named value (like a constant named age) or a function with a fixed result. Meanwhile a variable is something that can be changed, like a mutable object. I find that way of distinguishing makes sense at least in functional languages. Even in imperative languages, perhaps depending on the coding style.